# Dijkstra path finder in C

Tags: c, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm learning the [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and I am testing out this code from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/). I want the program to print the path for the shortest distance between 2 nodes as well.

I defined:

```c
int parent[V]
```

as a global variable to store the nodes that will give me the shortest path possible. And:

```c
int end_point = 5;
```

To set the end node as 5.

```c
// A C program for Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm. 
// The program is for adjacency matrix representation of the graph 

#include <limits.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>


// Number of vertices in the graph 
#define V 9 
  
// Define shortest path array
int parent[V];
int end_node = 5;

// A utility function to find the vertex with minimum distance value, from 
// the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree 
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[]) 
{ 
    // Initialize min value 
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index; 
  
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) 
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min) 
            min = dist[v], min_index = v; 
  
    return min_index; 
} 
  
// A utility function to print the constructed distance array 
void printSolution(int dist[]) 
{ 
    printf("Vertex \t\t Distance from Source\n"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]); 
} 

void printparent()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < end_node; i++){
        if(parent[i]){
             printf("%d --> ", parent[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Function that implements Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm 
// for a graph represented using adjacency matrix representation 
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src) 
{ 
    int dist[V]; // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the shortest 
    // distance from src to i 
  
    bool sptSet[V]; // sptSet[i] will be true if vertex i is included in shortest 
    // path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized 
  
    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false; 
  
    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0 
    dist[src] = 0; 
    parent[src] = 0;
  
    // Find shortest path for all vertices 
    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) { 
        // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices not 
        // yet processed. u is always equal to src in the first iteration. 
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet); 
  
        // Mark the picked vertex as processed 
        sptSet[u] = true; 
        
  
        // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex. 
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) 
  
            // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an edge from 
            // u to v, and total weight of path from src to  v through u is 
            // smaller than current value of dist[v] 
            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX 
                && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v]) {
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v]; 
                parent[v] = u;
            }
    } 
  
    // print the constructed distance array 
    printSolution(dist); 
} 
  
// driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{ 
    /* Let us create the example graph discussed above */
    int graph[V][V] = { { 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0 }, 
                        { 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0 }, 
                        { 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6 }, 
                        { 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0 } }; 
  
    dijkstra(graph, 0); 
    printparent();
  
    return 0; 
}
```

The program prints out the correct shortest distances between 0 and 5, which is 11, but does not print the correct route:

```
Vertex           Distance from Source
0                0
1                4
2                12
3                19
4                21
5                11
6                9
7                8
8                14
1 --> 2 --> 5 -->
```

The correct shortest route from 0 to 5 should be:

```
0 --> 7 --> 6 --> 5 -->
```

Which gives length 11.

How should I fix my code to print the correct shortest path?

For storing the shortest path in the array part, the code is as follows:

```
int array[100];
int a;

void printparent(){
     n = end_node;
     while(n != 0){
          array[a] = n;
          printf("%s --> ", n);
          n = parent[n];
          a++;
     }
}
```

Comment: In `printparent`, you treat `parent[]` as if it were a linear array of the path, but the array is really a map where `parent[v] == p`. So to follow the route, `u = end_node; while (u != 0) { print(u); u = parent[u]; }`. This will give you the correct path, but in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printparent()` function does not make sense to me at all.

In the first place, consider the iteration bounds of the loop within:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < end_node; i++){
> ```

How does it make sense to consider only the parents of nodes 0 through `end_node`?  The shortest path could very well pass through other nodes.

In the second place, consider the condition for printing:

> ```
>         if(parent[i]){
> ```

The `parent` array contains vertex numbers, which start from 0.  That condition will always skip a node whose parent is node 0, so it cannot print a correct shortest path if that path includes node 0 (as yours does).

But consider, moreover, the order in which you're printing parents, and the selection of parents you're printing.  If node `N` is on the shortest path, with parent `P`, then you want to print `N` immediately after printing `P`, but only by happenstance will that happen if you just traverse the `parent` array in index order.  And there's no reason to expect that this approach will reliably omit nodes that were added to the shortest path tree, but do not appear on the shortest path between the start and end nodes.

You need a completely different approach to print the shortest path.  It's actually more natural to print the reverse path:

- start by printing the end node;
- at each subsequent step, print `parent[n]`, where `n` is the node printed in the previous iteration
- stop when you reach the source node, or if you don't want to pass the source node as a parameter then stop when you reach a node that has no parent

(Of course, again, you do need a different way to designate "has no parent" than with `parent[i] == 0`.)

To print the path in the forward direction, you need to first trace it backward, as described, then print the results in reverse order.  You can do that by storing them in an array and then iterating backward over it, or by doing the path discovery recursively, printing each node after the recursive call returns.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I managed to print the route backwards using the code from the comment made by @M Oehm above, but since the while function is looping, how do I store every n into a different array and not affect the values of n in the loop?

Comment: @c_struggler, it's not quite clear to me what part you're uncertain about.  If you are going to exercise the option of collecting the shortest path nodes in an array, then you need to (1) declare a suitable array, and (2) declare and use a variable in which you track how many spots in it have been populated so far (which is also the index of the next available element).  That's altogether separate from `n`, or whatever you choose to call the variable in which you track node identifiers along the path.

Comment: Ok it's working perfectly now, thank you very much!